# FacebookSDK Error GADCustomEventBanner.h not found

Tags: xcode, linker, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

I've tried reinstalling the FacebookSDK framework a few times but all that gives me is linker errors.

The `#import "GADCustomEventBanner.h"` statement is located in the `FBAdMobCustomEventBanner.h` file. I'm not sure what to do here and I've even tried starting over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are adding the FacebookSDK.Framework folder into your project. If it appears as "FacebookSDK" in your projects framework folder, you did it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging the FacebookSDK.framework into Xcode.  That worked for me after I got this error